# Bouncy Castle Extract PGP Session Key from Public-Key Encrypted Session Packet

Tags: openssl, cryptography, bouncycastle, gnupg, openpgp

I have a PGP [Public-Key Encrypted Session Packet](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1) from which I would like to extract the session key so that I can decrypt the session key separately. I'm using the BouncyCastle library and am extracting the session key like this:

```
private static void outputSessionKey(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    BCPGInputStream input = new BCPGInputStream(PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(new FileInputStream(path)));
    Packet packet;
    while((packet = input.readPacket()) != null) {
        if (packet instanceof PublicKeyEncSessionPacket) {
            PublicKeyEncSessionPacket encPacket = (PublicKeyEncSessionPacket) packet;
            byte[] encKey = encPacket.getEncSessionKey()[0];
            FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("session_key_enc.bin");
            output.write(encKey);
            output.close();
        }
    }
    
    input.close();
}
```

I was expecting to then be able to decrypt the session key using openssl:

```
openssl rsautl -decrypt -in session_key_enc.bin -out session_key_decoded.bin -inkey private.pem
```

Where **session_key_enc.bin** is my encrypted session key in binary format and **private.pem** is the corresponding private key to the public key I used to encrypt my data in GPG. Before encrypting my data, I converted the public key portion of my RSA key pair into a PGP formatted key and imported it into GPG.

When I run the OpenSSL command, I get this error:

```
RSA operation error
140624851898072:error:0406506C:rsa routines:RSA_EAY_PRIVATE_DECRYPT:data greater than mod len:rsa_eay.c:518:
```

Upon examining **session_key_enc.bin** I found that the file is 258 bytes. This doesn't seem like it should be possible considering I'm using a 2048 bit RSA key and the spec indicates that the encrypted session key is modded by n:

> Algorithm Specific Fields for RSA encryption
> - multiprecision integer (MPI) of RSA encrypted value m**e mod n.

> The value "m" in the above formulas is derived from the session key
> as follows.  First, the session key is prefixed with a one-octet
> algorithm identifier that specifies the symmetric encryption
> algorithm used to encrypt the following Symmetrically Encrypted Data
> Packet.  Then a two-octet checksum is appended, which is equal to the
> sum of the preceding session key octets, not including the algorithm
> identifier, modulo 65536.  This value is then encoded as described in
> PKCS#1 block encoding EME-PKCS1-v1_5 in Section 7.2.1 of [RFC3447] to
> form the "m" value used in the formulas above.  See Section 13.1 of
> this document for notes on OpenPGP's use of PKCS#1.

Any advice on how to solve this puzzle would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you split apart the first few header bytes of the packet (or made sure Bouncy Castle is already doing so)? `pgpdump -pi` should also print the session key as integer value, you should be able to compare the result of your Java code with this one.

Comment: @JensErat It turns out that Bouncy Castle outputs the session key in MPI format with the first two bytes representing the total side. After stripping those out, I am able to decrypt the session key but am still not able to get any sensible key out of the decoded raw bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Bouncy Castle exports encrypted session keys using MPI format where the first 2 bytes are the length. This resolves the original issue where I was unable to decrypt the session key because it was 258 bytes instead of 256.

I am marking this question as answered despite still being unable to decrypt the file using --override-session-key and the raw bytes of the now-decrypted session key.

Comment: hello, would like your advise on setting bouncy castle for connecting my C client. I am trying to set backport gnutls application (mandos-server) with bouncy. any help will be appreciated